# Possible to modify but not replace a method's prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Let's say I have a method Object.getNumber() and I want to make a small change to the results of that method, for example add 1 to the result, and no I can't access that method's code.

Any way to do this with its prototype? I would need to access the method within the defineProperty call I suppose.

`Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'getNumber',{ get: function () { ... } });`

Comment: If the method is `Object.getNumber`, then assigning to `Object.prototype.getNumber` won't help. You will need to overwrite `Object.getNumber` itself.

Comment: Is that really a method of the native `Object`, or some custom namespace?

Comment: @Bergi I'm modifying a native method in Element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always replace the original method in the prototype, but keep the original somewhere in the local variable. Something like this:

```
Object.prototype.getNumber = (function() {
    let originalFn = Object.prototype.getNumber;

    return function() {
        let originalResult = originalFn.apply(this, arguments);

        return originalResult + 1;
    };
})();
```

Comment: The apply function answered my next question, you're on top of it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A method is just a function that you can pass around so you can simply apply that function after another:

```
const getNumber = Object.prototype.getNumber;
Object.prototype.getNumber = function() {
  const result = getNumber();
  return result + 1;
};
```

But modifying a native prototype is not good practice, especially `Object.prototype` as that affects too many things.